# Bridge single port between interfaces

Tags: networking, server, vpn

I followed a guide that helped me setup my OpenVPN on my Ubuntu 16.04 x64 server in such a way that all traffic from applications running as the `vpn` user, will be routed via the vpn connection, and everything else will bypass this.

The only issue is, I can't access the transmission-daemon web interface now, because that traffic is routed via the VPN connection too.

I can access it from the server itself, because it's the localhost, but I can't access it from my LAN.

Is there a way to forward / bridge this single port (9091) between my `eth0` and `tun0` interfaces? (Keeping in mind the `tun0` interface may at times disappear / reappear when the VPN connection is reset).

To get an idea of my current configuration, this was the guide that I followed: https://www.htpcguides.com/force-torrent-traffic-vpn-split-tunnel-debian-8-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by running `TinyProxy` on the public connection, allowing me to connect to the services running via the VPN connection via `localhost`.

If a better solution is available, I'm all ears. But for now, this works.